Does splice() always leave empty strings in place of the spliced elements, instead of cleanly removing them?
I am learning JS from SuperSimpleDev's tutorial and got stuck.
I am confused about the functionality of splice(). Online I am only finding examples where splice() cleanly removes elements. But it's leaving me with empty strings instead.
I have an array of to-do elements, and each to-do element has a delete button beside it, which, on being clicked, should disappear along with the to-do text. I logged my array on the console after splicing, and saw that I was getting left with [todo1, '', '', todo4] and so on. So the delete buttons were still being displayed (beside the empty string elements which I didn't know were there) even though I had spliced those elements. The left behind delete buttons:
function renderTodoList() {
  const inputElement = document.querySelector('.js-name-input');
  const name = inputElement.value;

  todoList.push(name);

  let todoListHTML = '';

  for(let i=0; i<todoList.length; i++){
    const todo = todoList[i];
    const html = `
      <p>
        ${todo}
        <button onclick="
          todoList.splice(${i},1);
          renderTodoList();
        ">Delete</button>
      </p>
    `;
    todoListHTML += html;
  }

  console.log(todoListHTML);

  document.querySelector('.js-display-todo').innerHTML = todoListHTML;

  inputElement.value = '';

  console.log(todoList);
}


Every time you delete an element, you call renderTodoList, which pushes a new element.

.splice NEVER "leaves empty strings" in place of the spliced content, why would it use empty strings in the first place? ... in fact, splice with only 2 arguments (as in your code) only ever removes 0 or 1 elements (depending if ${i} is < array.length or not)

here are some idea i got for u ..
function rendertodolist(){
const inputElement = document.querySelector(".js-name-input");
const name = inputElement.value;

todoList.push(name);

let todoListHTML = '';

for(let i=0; i<todoList.lenght; i++){
const todo = todoList[i];
const html =`
      <p>
        ${todo}
        <button onclick="
          todoList = todoList.filter((_, index) => index !== ${i});
          renderTodoList();
        ">Delete</button>
      </p>
    `;
todoListHTML +=html;
}
console.log(todoLISTHTML);
document.querySelector('.js-display-todo').innerHTML = todoListHTML;
inputElement.value = '';
console.log(todoList);
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
